# Need to extract specific word in unix

Tags: unix, grep

I want to extract the specific word i.e `PassThroughHandlerJob:  2299 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 pending` from the below text file.

In the log file 2299 succeeded count is changing everyday. And the count may differ every day for failed, pending and success.

**NewFile.txt**

```
2014-07-10 22:28:13,193 INFO [mainScheduler_Worker-28]     [com.myvest.sps.scheduler.jobs.AbstractDistributedJob] Checked the status of 2299 work units for job PassThroughHandlerJob:  2299 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 pending

2014-07-10 22:28:21,859 INFO [mainScheduler_Worker-28]     [com.myvest.sps.scheduler.jobs.success.PassThroughHandlerJob] Job PassThroughHandlerJob.PassThroughHandlerJob finished
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this particular task you should be able to use grep;

```
$ grep PassThroughHandlerJob: log.txt
PassThroughHandlerJob: 2299 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 pending 2014-07-10 22:28:21,859 INFO
```

Answer (score 1):

You can have:

```
egrep -o 'PassThroughHandlerJob:\s+[0-9]+ succeeded, [0-9]+ failed, [0-9]+ pending' file
```

Or just normal `grep`:

```
grep -o 'PassThroughHandlerJob:[[:space:]]\+[0-9]\+ succeeded, [0-9]\+ failed, [0-9]\+ pending' file
```

Comment: grep -o 'PassThroughHandlerJob:[[:space:]]\+[0-9]\+ succeeded, [0-9]\+ failed, [0-9]\+ pending' file command is working fine thank you so much